# Merge Two Speaker Audio Files using dolby.ai

Tags: dolby-audio-api

I have two source audio files, recorded locally from an online video call.

I want to match their loudness, enhance the audio quality, and merge into one file.

How do I do this with the dolby.io media APIs?

https://docs.dolby.io/media-apis/docs/analyze-api-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what I would do here is use the [Transcode API](https://docs.dolby.io/media-apis/docs/transcode-api-guide) to stitch the files together then call the [Enhance API](https://docs.dolby.io/media-apis/docs/enhance-api-guide) to normalize the files.